# Connect a server with android

Tags: android

I want to connect a server with an android app and receive data like emails. Is it possible to save this data in text or xml files? The data will be saved in the assets-folder.

Pease help me if anyone has a solution for it..

Any help is appreciated..Thanks..

Comment: First of all you should find what type of connection you wanted to make with the server like TCP/UDP/FTP/html/SSH . what kind of server you wanted to connect

Comment: The server is an ssh server with an java ee application.

Comment: JSON is a good way to communicate with webserver. You wanted to do a http request like http://yourdomain.com/getMydata
and get the output from the url?

Comment: The "assets" pseudo-folder is read only at runtime, however the android documentation describes a variety of writable storage options.  Normal networking at least in the outgoing connection direction is supported.  You are likely going to need to clarify your requirement before you can get any more targeted help.

Comment: i want to connect the server and get data like an mail server. The data will be save in 3 files in the assets folder (mydata1.txt, mydata2.txt and mydata3.txt). The files will be read from the app and the strings will be copied in a listview. My problem is how to get the data from the server into my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is

Take a look at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#SMTP_transport_example
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html
http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

Here is a small example:

```
public void connectToEmailServer() {
    String host = "10.0.0.1";
    int port = 25;

    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        String serverMsg;
        String clientMsg = "HELO";

        while ((serverMsg = in.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.v("TAG", "<server>" + serverMsg + "</server>");
            Log.v("Client: " + clientMsg);
            out.println(clientMsg);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStacktrace();
    }
```